# Top Bar elements not lined up

Tags: css, zurb-foundation-6

What am I doing wrong here using Foundation 6 top bar to cause the menu items to not line up.:

```
<div class="top-bar">
  <div class="top-bar-left">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menu-text"><a href='#'>HandyMan!</a></li>                 
      <li><a href="/gallery">Gallery</a></li>                          
    </ul>
  </div>  
</div>
```

As can be seen in this JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4ky7jjja/

I'm using documentation from here:
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/top-bar.html

I've added a hyperlink but surely that would be a normal thing to do on a menu bar like this.

Comment: maybe it has to do with the class or where it stands ? https://jsfiddle.net/4ky7jjja/1/

Answer (score 1):

The class `menu-text` on the first `<li>` is adding extra padding that the second one (with the link) does not have.  Either remove that class, add it to the other `li`, or override the padding with your own css.

Comment: Thanks... I'm still slightly confused - Why is that not the case in the original TopBar documentation?  The only thing I've added is a link into the menu text list item.

Comment: Exactly.  But the link you added does not have the extra padding.  You need to add it.